# ¿Por qué mi trigger UPDATE no me deja insertar más información a mi tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En sí tengo un error, que cuando inicio el trigger, no me deja insertar más datos a la table, y cada vez que pasa dice que fue "insertado":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero este no se ve en la tabla cuando se usa

```
Select *From Marcas_De_Jugos
```

y sale vacía la tabla cuando se utiliza, es como si lo mandara a otro lugar.

En sí no sé por qué pasa.

```
use  angel#6

create table Marcas_De_Jugos(
Codigo int primary key,
NEmpresa varchar (50),
Nombre varchar (100),
cantidad int,
valor float,
disponible varchar(20));

drop table Marcas_De_Jugos

insert into Marcas_De_Jugos (Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor,disponible)
values (12518521,'Jugos de Toriel','Jugito Toriel',2142,$15,''),
 (12414122,'Leches de toro','Jugo de toro',2531,$20,''),
 (14153515,'Daniel Jugos','Blox Fruit',4151,$15,''),
 (24525624,'Marcelo Mira abajo','Marcelito Fresa',5167,$18,''),
 (45131581,'Jugos Furry','Leche de Furry, Sabor Naranja',1412,$15,''),
 (98213985,'Toño Fruit','Marandana Toño',5313,$20,''),
 (45128951,'Rusoo Macs','Manza Russ',1452,$25,''),
 (81535115,'MASA JUGO','Balanceada',5123,$25,''),
 (21541515,'Phoenix','Cristol fresa',4122,$20,''),
 (61245881,'GodHuman','GodMango',1124,$15,'');


 Select *From Marcas_De_Jugos

--Upper 
Select Upper (NEmpresa) As XD from Marcas_De_Jugos

--lower
Select lower (NEmpresa) As Jugos_Bebidas_Marcelo from Marcas_De_Jugos

-- substring
select substring (NEmpresa,5,10) AS Nombres_Extraidos from Marcas_De_Jugos

--Len
select len (NEmpresa) as Logitud_texto from Marcas_De_Jugos  --Sirve para calcular la longitud del texto como: Ang g (5)

--getdate
Select getdate ()
Select Year(getdate()),
 month(getdate()),
 day(getdate())

set dateformat'dmy'
--Format

select format (12518521,'###-###-##') as CodigoDeJugos;
select Nombre,Codigo,format (Year(Getdate()),'##-##') as fecha_de_Marcas from Marcas_De_Jugos

--Min 
Select min(cantidad) from Marcas_De_Jugos

insert into Marcas_De_Jugos(Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor)
values(61245181,'GcdHuman','GodMang2',1144,$15);

drop table Marcas_De_Jugos

insert into Marcas_De_Jugos(Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor,disponible)
values(23214821,'fhfi','3i3es',0,$12,'')
```

```
--Trigger
create trigger Marcas_NullIB
on Marcas_De_Jugos
instead of insert
Not for replication 
as
    update Marcas_De_Jugos set disponible = null where cantidad =0
    update Marcas_De_Jugos set disponible = 'Disponible' where cantidad > 0
    update Marcas_De_Jugos set disponible = 'Debe' where cantidad < 0
go
```

Comment: Porque creas la tabla y luego la borras?

Comment: No entiendo si la primera porción de código la ejecutas seguida o no, pero haces drop table y luego haces un insert a la tabla que acabas de borrar, no tiene mucho sentido

Comment: En si, es que lo ejecuto por partes (crear la tabla, y poner los datos en si), en si no todo. A si que no se va borrar, solo lo hago porque estaba intentando resolverlo, y cada vez que fallaba le daba a borrar y ejecutaba.

Comment: y el trigger cuando lo creas? el orden es importante...

Comment: es mas.. donde esta el campo total en esa tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que has creado un trigger de un tipo `Instead of` y no has aplicado la sentencia de inserción.

Este tipo de desencadenador, se produce antes de insertar, y aborta la misma inserción, y por tanto si no lo indicas explicitamente, no se produce.

La primera solución, es cambiar el tipo.

```
create table Marcas_De_Jugos(
Codigo int primary key,
NEmpresa varchar (50),
Nombre varchar (100),
cantidad int,
valor float,
disponible varchar(20));
GO

--Trigger

create trigger Marcas_NullIB
on Marcas_De_Jugos
AFTER INSERT
Not for replication 
as
    update Marca 
        Set disponible = null 
        FROM Marcas_De_Jugos Marca INNER JOIN inserted ON Marca.Codigo = inserted.Codigo
    where inserted.cantidad =0;

    update Marca 
        set disponible = 'Disponible' 
        FROM Marcas_De_Jugos Marca INNER JOIN inserted ON Marca.Codigo = inserted.Codigo
    where inserted.cantidad > 0;

    update Marca 
        set disponible = 'Debe' 
        FROM Marcas_De_Jugos Marca INNER JOIN inserted ON Marca.Codigo = inserted.Codigo
    where inserted.cantidad < 0
go
```

El segundo problema, es que una sentencia update, se produce sobre todas las filas, y se supone que lo que tienes que hacer, es modificar el disponible de la fila que se está insertando. No de todas.

Para esto usamos la pseudotabla `inserted`.

```
insert into Marcas_De_Jugos (Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor,disponible)
values (12518521,'Jugos de Toriel','Jugito Toriel',2142,$15,''),
 (12414122,'Leches de toro','Jugo de toro',2531,$20,''),
 (14153515,'Daniel Jugos','Blox Fruit',4151,$15,''),
 (24525624,'Marcelo Mira abajo','Marcelito Fresa',5167,$18,''),
 (45131581,'Jugos Furry','Leche de Furry, Sabor Naranja',1412,$15,''),
 (98213985,'Toño Fruit','Marandana Toño',5313,$20,''),
 (45128951,'Rusoo Macs','Manza Russ',1452,$25,''),
 (81535115,'MASA JUGO','Balanceada',5123,$25,''),
 (21541515,'Phoenix','Cristol fresa',4122,$20,''),
 (61245881,'GodHuman','GodMango',1124,$15,'');

 
insert into Marcas_De_Jugos(Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor)
values(61245181,'GcdHuman','GodMang2',1144,$15);

insert into Marcas_De_Jugos(Codigo,NEmpresa,Nombre,cantidad,valor,disponible)
values(23214821,'fhfi','3i3es',0,$12,'')
```

Y si buscas los datos, ahora si están.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Marcas_De_Jugos;
```

[image: res]

[Trigger after](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)

[Trigger instead of](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/03/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-instead-of/)

Comment: Muchas gracias :D!!!